# java's SystemTray not working on Gnome 3.14

Tags: java, awt, gnome-3

I'm trying to put a Java SystemTray icon on gnome's notification panel (I'm using OpenSuse 13.2, that uses gnome 3.14).

Its not working, although SystemTray.isSupported() is returning "true". I'm not seeing any icon on the screen. I was expecting it to appear next to OpenSuse's notification area.

This is the main's code:

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        //checking for support
        if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
            System.out.println("System tray is not supported !!! ");
            return;
        }
        SystemTray systemTray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("icon.ico");

        //popupmenu
        PopupMenu trayPopupMenu = new PopupMenu();

        //1t menuitem for popupmenu
        MenuItem action = new MenuItem("Action");
        action.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Action Clicked");
            }
        });
        trayPopupMenu.add(action);

        //2nd menuitem of popupmenu
        MenuItem close = new MenuItem("Close");
        close.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        trayPopupMenu.add(close);

        //setting tray icon
        TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "SystemTray Demo", trayPopupMenu);
        //adjust to default size as per system recommendation 
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);

        try {
            systemTray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException awtException) {
            awtException.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("end of main");

    }//end of main
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: I've edited the question and added code